# Удаление повторяющихся элементов двумерного списка Python

Tags: python, list

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. Есть список

```
list1 = [[],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [7, 9, 11, 15],
 [3, 5, 6, 8, 10],
 [31, 56, 71],
 [3, 7, 9, 11],
 [127, 128, 129]]
```

нужно получить список

```
list2 = [[], 
 [3, 5, 7], 
 [9, 11, 15], 
 [6, 8, 10], 
 [31, 56, 71], 
 [], 
 [127, 128, 129]]
```

т.е. убрать все повторяющиеся значения.

```
list1 = [[], [3, 5, 7], [7, 9, 11, 15], [3, 5, 6, 8, 10], [31, 56, 71], [3, 7, 9, 11], [127, 128, 129]]
list2 = []

for x1 in list1:
    list2.append([])
    for y1 in x1:
        for x2 in range(len(list1)):
            for y2 in x1:
                if y1 not in list2:
                    list2.append(y1)
print(list2)
```

Код выводит:

```
[[], [], 3, 5, 7, [], 9, 11, 15, [], 6, 8, 10, [], 31, 56, 71, [], [], 127, 128, 129]
```

Если я пишу `list2[x2].append(y1)`, то программа завершается с ошибкой `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [[],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [7, 9, 11, 15],
 [3, 5, 6, 8, 10],
 [31, 56, 71],
 [3, 7, 9, 11],
 [127, 128, 129]]

list2 = []

for line in list1:
    list2.append([]) 
    for elem in line:
        for line_2 in list2:
            if elem in line_2:
                break
        else:
            list2[-1].append(elem)

print(list2)
```

Уж очень вы намудрили с вложенными циклами. К тому же, элементы нужно добавлять во внутренний список, а не во внешний.

---

Результат:

```
[[], 
 [3, 5, 7], 
 [9, 11, 15], 
 [6, 8, 10], 
 [31, 56, 71], 
 [], 
 [127, 128, 129]]
```

Comment: Если памяти достаточно, то можно ускорить, добавляя элементы так же в set и проверяя их вхождение в этот set, а не в подсписки list2. При больших размерах списков это прямо сильно должно ускорить.